# Installing Visual Studio 2015 with Update 2 throws error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Getting this error during install of the latest version of Visual Studio. I've tried the web installer and the iso version of 2015 with update 2 and can't get past this step. Any idea how I would clean up an old install of Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Minimum Runtime?

> Product: Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Minimum Runtime - 14.0.23918 --
>   Error 1714.The older version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Minimum
>   Runtime - 14.0.23918 cannot be removed.  Contact your technical
>   support group.  System Error 1612.

I get the same error when trying to install the redistributable from this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51682

[image]
[image]

Comment: go to control panel->program & features and try to uninstall the older version. What happens?

Comment: Its not listed in Programs & Features :) I have MANY versions of the Visual C++ runtime installed but none are Visual C++ 2015 versions

Comment: Its looks like MS will never fix that problem :) When I got similar error: I downloaded [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) from MS site and installed it first (both x86 and 64 versions). Than I started VS setup again and it completed without errors.

Comment: That version installs but makes no difference to the visual studio install. This updated version https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51682 throws the same error as the visual studio install

Comment: I checked the version 14.0.23918 and this is the Update 2 RTM. So I have no idea why it tries to remove it.

Comment: I wonder if there is something in the registry I can remove/change to fix this. At the moment I can't install VS which is kind of a major issue for me